# The user can't edit/view the records of other users. How to achieve this in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

A user can't edit/view the records of other users. Edit/View is allowed only to the owner of the record. When the passes id of other user's record, the application allows him to edit it.

I need to verify the ownership before editing or viewing the record.

My question is almost same as this.

[ASP.NET MVC: Verify that editing record is allowed (ownership)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417248/asp-net-mvc-verify-that-editing-record-is-allowed-ownership)

Comment: What's different about your question from the one you linked to that makes this question not a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the logged-in user -

```
public static Guid? LoggedInUserGuid()
        {
            var loggedInUser = Membership.GetUser(false);
            if (loggedInUser != null)
            {
                return (Guid)Membership.GetUser(false).ProviderUserKey;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

If the LoggedInUserGuid is the same as the request record then ... else ....

Answer (score 0):

I guess then that if you want to ensure that the users only edits rows that they added in a table you would have to include the Guid in the row and verify it with every modification